# Mysql table multiple foreign key

Tags: mysql, database

I have three table users, cars and enquiries and their design is like:
**users:**
id ,name, email
**cars:**
id,user_id,name
**Enquiry:**
id, car_id,description

I just want to know that should I have to keep `user_id` in `Enquiry table` or not.As I know that i can fetch user detail with reference of `car_id` of `cars` table.what is the best way to manage these kind of things.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no need to do that. As you can fetch enquiry details based on unique car_id of the user from cars table.

Comment: is there any drawback if i keep `user_id` in `enquiry` table

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the user_id from Enquiry table, you have an implicit assumption in your design that the enquiry is aways created by the car owner.

Is this assumption acceptable to you?

This may be very subjective, but talking about correctness, my opinion is that you should keep the user_id because Enquiry itself is an entity and should have its own owner.

Comment: If you look it at a different way then Enquiry is about a particular car.

Comment: @Er_sherlockian that's why I said it could be subjective. However, even so, it may still make sense to have the creator there.

Comment: @Er_sherlockian I have also ensured that creator id(s) are maintained in other tables also despite having a JOIN way to get data. This helps me in avoiding long JOINs especially when I have 4 or more tables being joined. Problem is that there is a chance that due to some bug or so, creator id may have mismatch. I am trying to implement combined foreign key constraint to avoid mismatch..but unable to do so in MySQL

Answer (score 0):

It is based on your reports but I would say, you will not require the extra user_id as everytime you would be joining all the table for detailing the user info and car info with the Enquiry taken.